# how to overcome the limitation of IN cause in sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

I have written an sql query like :

```
select field1, field2 from table_name;
```

The problem is this query will return 1 million records/ or more than 100k records.
I have a directory in which I have input files (around 20,000 to 50,000 records) that contain field1 . This is the main data I am concerned with.
Using perl script, I am extracting  from the directory.
But , if I write a query like :

```
select field1 , field2 from table_name 
where field1 in (need to write a query to take field1 from directory);
```

If I use IN cause then it has limitation of processing 1000 entries, then how should I overcome the limitation of IN cause?

Comment: What database system has a 1K limit for `in`?

Comment: @eakron: Oracle has a limit of 1000 literals (i.e. constants) in the IN clause. Other DBMS have similar limits.

Answer (score 4):

In any DBMS, I would insert them into a temporary table and perform a `JOIN` to workaround the IN clause limitation on the size of the list.

E.g.

```
CREATE TABLE #idList
(
    ID INT
)
INSERT INTO #idList VALUES(1)
INSERT INTO #idList VALUES(2)
INSERT INTO #idList VALUES(3)

SELECT * 
FROM 
    MyTable m 
    JOIN #idList AS t 
    ON m.id = t.id
```

In SQL Server 2005, in one of our previous projects, we used to convert this list of values that are a result of querying another data store (lucene index) into XML and pass it as XML variable in the SQL query and convert it into a table using the `nodes()` function on XML data types and perform a `JOIN` with that.

```
DECLARE @IdList XML
SELECT @idList = '
<Requests>
    <Request id="1" />
    <Request id="2" />
    <Request id="3" />
</Requests>'

SELECT * 
FROM 
    MyTable m 
    JOIN (
            SELECT id.value('(@id)[1]', 'INT') as 'id' 
            FROM @idList.nodes('/Requests/Request') as T(id)
         ) AS t 
    ON m.id = t.id
```

Comment: I have oracle and sql as a database.Also, I didn't get your xml point. Please could you elaborate with an example ? it would be so kind if you do so.

Comment: Please see the update about how I would use the temp table option in any DB that supports temp tables (Oracle does support) and XML table option in SQL Server 2005 or higher.

Comment: @Vikdor I don't like the approach of recreating the whole table every time the query is run. Imho, it's better to do this once then update when neccessary.

Comment: @ShubhraGarg: *SQL* is ***not*** a database. It's a query language. I assume you mean "Microsoft SQL Server" (I have added the tags to your question)

Comment: @aefxx, Completely agree, but the values for `field1` are coming from the application layer which is a result of searching (querying) in the directories (another data store).

Comment: @Vikdor Then the application layer would have to be responsible to correctly propagate the updates (I've given an example in my answer).

Answer (score 1):

Vikdor is right, you shouldn't be querying this with an `IN()` clause, it's faster and more memory efficient to use a table to `JOIN`.

Expanding on his answer I would recommend the following approach:

1. Get a list of all input files via Perl
2. Think of some clever way to compute a hash value for your list that is unique and based on all input files (I'd recommend the filenames or similar)
3. This hash will serve as the name of the table that stores the input filenames (think of it as a quasi temporary table that gets discarded once the hash changes)
4. `JOIN` that table to return the correct records

For step 2. you could either use a cronjob or compute whenever the query is actually needed (which would delay the response, though). To get this right you need to consider how likely it is that files are added/removed.

For step 3. you would need some logic that drops the previously generated tables once the current hash value differs from last execution, then recreate the table named after the current hash.

For the quasi temporary table names I'd recommend something along the lines of

```
input_files_XXX (.i.e. prefix_<hashvalue>)
```

which makes it easier to know what stale tables to drop.

Answer (score 0):

You could split your 50'000 ids in 50 lists of 1000 ids, do a query for each such list, and collect the result sets in perl.

Comment: Hi @meriton, How I should proceed with your with your answer. How to re-iterate the query for 50 lists ?Please provide me with and example. Is that I should do a join of the results of 50 lists ?

Answer (score 0):

Oracle wise, the best solution with using a temporary table - which without indexing won't give you much performance is to use a nested tabled type.

CREATE TYPE my_ntt is table of directory_rec;

Then create a function f1 that returns a variable of my_ntt type and use in the query.

select field1 , field2 from table_name where field1 in table (cast (f1 as my_ntt));

Comment: Could you please post an example ?